# Git merge says files were 'deleted by us' when they were not

Tags: git, merge

I'm new to git and am struggling with it a bit.

I was working on about 5 files and went to push them to my remote repo. I was expecting merge errors, but what came back was `deleted by us` message for 2 of the 5 files I was working on.

I most certainly did not delete these files, nor change their paths. Would anyone know why this has happened and what I can do about it?

```
git push ${repo_name} ${current_branch_refspec}
Push branch to remote

git merge ${current_branch_refspec}
Merging feature into testing branch
```

Comment: "deleted by us" means that the files were deleted on the current branch.

Comment: Please show a git session which results in this error. You should describe the directory hierarchy of your project and show the exact commands that lead up to this error along with all output along the way. You can replace file names and branch names with dummy names if you want to protect your data.

Comment: "went to push them" - you don't (can't) get merge errors on push. Can you explain exactly what you *did* do, and what happened?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm assuming he must have pulled, but let the OP clarify this.

Comment: @GregHewgill added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all files back and commit again.

```
git add .
```

or

```
git add -A
```

Then commit

```
git commit
```

If you want to remove files then you can use `git rm` instead of `git add`